# Linux Catalyst and three monitors

Tags: linux, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, xorg, amd-radeon

I just switched from opensource ATI driver to catalyst because I had many crashes on my Linux box when playing flash videos.

It looks like with fglrx my system is more stable, but I lost my third monitor and cannot enable it any more.

I have Cedar card:

```
[   723.679] (**) fglrx(0): AMD 2D Acceleration Architecture enabled
[   723.679] (--) fglrx(0): Chipset: "AMD Radeon HD 5450  " (Chipset = 0x68f9)
[   723.679] (--) fglrx(0): (PciSubVendor = 0x1787, PciSubDevice = 0x2291)
[   723.679] (==) fglrx(0): board vendor info: third party graphics adapter - NOT original AMD
```

With three outputs: DisplayPort, DVI and VGA. xrandr:

```
[root@serenity ~]# xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
DFP1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     60.00  
   1400x1050     60.00  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1360x1024     60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      60.00  
   1280x960      75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      60.00    75.00  
   1280x768      75.02    60.02  
   1280x720      75.02    60.02  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
DFP2 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     60.00  
   1400x1050     60.00  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1360x1024     60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      60.00  
   1280x960      75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      60.00    75.00  
   1280x768      75.02    60.02  
   1280x720      75.02    60.02  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
CRT1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
CRT2 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1680x1050     59.95 +
   1400x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      59.95  
   1360x1024     59.95  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x864      59.95    75.00  
   1280x768      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    67.00    59.94
```

I cannot enable CRT2 display with xrandr:

```
[zork@serenity ~]$ xrandr --output CRT2 --auto
xrandr: Configure crtc 2 failed
```

Catalyst Control Center reports CRT display as disabled and there is no option to enable it.

My xorg.conf:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "aticonfig Layout"
    Screen      0  "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0" 0 0
EndSection

Section "Module"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "0-DFP2"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
    Option      "PreferredMode" "1920x1080"
    Option      "TargetRefresh" "60"
    Option      "Position" "0 0"
    Option      "Rotate" "normal"
    Option      "Disable" "false"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "0-DFP1"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
    Option      "PreferredMode" "1920x1080"
    Option      "TargetRefresh" "60"
    Option      "Position" "1920 0"
    Option      "Rotate" "normal"
    Option      "Disable" "false"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "0-CRT2"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
    Option      "Disable" "true"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    Option      "Monitor-DFP2" "0-DFP2"
    Option      "Monitor-DFP1" "0-DFP1"
    Option      "Monitor-CRT2" "0-CRT2"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
    Device     "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Virtual   3840 1920
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

I tried to set "Disable" to "false" on 0-CRT2 and add PreferredMode, Position and TargetRefresh but it did not help. Catalyst Control Center when run as root overwrites those changes and disables CRT2.

I am using xorg 1.14 and catalyst 14.4 under Arch Linux.

Comment: It looks like opensource drivers use some unsupported feature and allow driver to use three monitors in contrast to AMD drivers, where it is disabled by design. I can use any two outputs of my card, but not three with catalyst drivers.

I decided to order sapphire flex card, which has two DVI and display port converted to HDMI and *should* support three monitors under Linux with catalyst drivers.

Comment: I stumbled upon this post upon my problems to have 2 monitors + TV working assembled on my Radeon 280X. It seems... it seems it will just not work, unless I do some magic around :-(